# Warning: Undefined array key "firstname"and lastname and email

Tags: arrays, key, undefined

```
<?php
    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $errors=[
        "firstNameError"=>'',
        "lastNameError"=>'',
        "emailError"=>''
       ];
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            if(empty($firstname)){
            $errors['firstNameError']="enter first name";
            }
            if(empty($lastname)){
            $errors['lastNameError']="enter last name";
            }
            if(empty($email)){
            $errors['emailError']="enter email ";
            }elseif (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['emailError']="enter email true";
             }
            if(!array_filter( $errors)){
                $firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["firstname"]);
                $lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["lastname"]);
                $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);
                $sql="INSERT INTO user(firstname,lastname,email) VALUES(  '$firstname' , '$lastname' , '$email')";
                if( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {

                       header("Location:". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                   }else {
                       echo "error :".mysqli_error($conn);
                     }
            }
    }
?>
<?php

?>

<?php 
 include './inc/db.php';
 include './inc/select.php';
 include './inc/db_close.php';
 include_once './parts/header.php';?>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">

        <label for="firstname">first name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo  $firstname?>" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        <div><?php echo  $errors['firstNameError']?></div>


        <label for="lastanme">last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"  value="<?php echo  $lastname?>"id="lastanme" placeholder="Last Name">
        <div><?php echo  $errors['lastNameError']?></div>


        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo  $email?>" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <div><?php echo  $errors['emailError']?></div>

        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvcmT.png)

When I enter the index.php page for the first time, I get this error
Warning: Undefined array key "firstname" in C:\Users\ali\Documents\my_pro\php\htdocs\pro\winernure\index.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "lastname" in C:\Users\ali\Documents\my_pro\php\htdocs\pro\winernure\index.php on line 4

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\Users\ali\Documents\my_pro\php\htdocs\pro\winernure\index.php on line 5